# Fragment add exit custom animation not working working when fragment is Added Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

The custom exit animation works for `replace` but not for `add`

```
getNavFragment()
        .childFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
            enter,
            exit,
            popEnter,
            popExit
        )
        .add(R.id.fl_fragment_container, fragment, tag)
        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
        .apply {
            if (shouldAddToBackStack)
                addToBackStack(tag)
        }
        .commit()
```